# connect elasticsearch like jdbc url

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc

can I manage this :
connect to my elasticsearch server in a way similar to jdbc, like:

```
url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.11.11:6673/my_db?characterEncoding=utf8"
```

Comment: which server side platform are u uisng

Answer (score 1):

```
Connection conn = 
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:elasticsearch:user=myuseraccount;password=mypassword;");

boolean ret = stat.execute("SELECT * FROM DocumentDB");
ResultSet rs=stat.getResultSet();
while(rs.next()){
  for(int i=1;i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++)
  {
    System.out.println(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) +"="+rs.getString(i));
  }
}
```

this is an example
refer('https://www.cdata.com/drivers/elasticsearch/jdbc/')

Comment: Just curious, if you are using it, is it possible to some "big" GROUP BY with?

Comment: While the driver is free, unfortunately it requires licensed elasticsearch server

Answer (score 0):

No you cant natively, elasticsearch have only a HTTP API or transport API.

There are some driver to allow this, or you could use something like Spark Thrift to act as JDBC gateway with the official plugin elastic4hadoop, so you can query with SQL against elasticsearch via Spark.

- https://fr.hortonworks.com/tutorial/spark-sql-thrift-server-example/
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/2.3/spark.html

Answer (score 0):

> [Elasticsearch's SQL JDBC
>   driver](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/sql-jdbc.html)
>   is a rich, fully featured JDBC driver for Elasticsearch. It is a Type
>   4 driver, meaning it is a platform independent, standalone, Direct to
>   Database, pure Java driver that converts JDBC calls to Elasticsearch
>   SQL.
>
> #### Installation
>
> The JDBC driver can be obtained from:
>
> Dedicated page
>             [elastic.co](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/jdbc-client)
>   provides links, typically for manual downloads.
>   Maven dependency
>             [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)-compatible
>   tools can retrieve it automatically as a dependency:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
>   <artifactId>x-pack-sql-jdbc</artifactId>
>   <version>7.0.0-alpha2</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> from artifacts.elastic.co/maven by adding it to the repositories list:
>
> ```
> <repositories>
>   <repository>
>     <id>elastic.co</id>
>     <url>https://artifacts.elastic.co/maven</url>
>   </repository>
> </repositories>
> ```

<sub>**Source:** [SQL JDBC Elasticsearch | Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/sql-jdbc.html)</sub>